# Find Text and buttons on any app window

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, user32

I want to be able to access an application and be able to access the buttons on the forms. I have looked into user32.dll and spy++ but what I found is that this method can only access winform windows. I want to be able to access by clicking on their buttons and getting their text. Is there a simple way of doing this or are programs these programs programmatically inaccessible?

Comment: Your best bet is UI Automation. Use the *Inspect.exe* tool to verify, whether your target application exposes the required interfaces.

Comment: Hi, I checked inspect.exe out and it is really handy. There are some apps where it fails on but it doesn't really matter as it would work on most others. I have done some research on UI Automation and found the white library. Will look into it if its better than the standard UI automation library .net provides. Thanks!